How to unescape HTML entities in Java?
In my database, I have a escaped HTML string that contains, among other HTML Entities, &#119871;.
If I display it in a HTML file, I can see the symbol that I expect: .
According to https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D43F it is called "Mathematical Italic Capital L" and could also be represented as HTML entity as &#x1D43F;.
However, I want to display that string in a PDF file, so I am trying to unescape
&#119871; in my Java application.
I have tried some different methods, and none worked as I intended:



method
output




org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#119871;")
퐿


org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("&#119871;");
퐿


org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#119871;");
ݐ¿


org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("&#119871;");
ݐ¿


org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.unescape("&#119871;");
ݐ¿


org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities("&#119871;", true);
ݐ¿


org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml("&#119871;")
ݐ¿



Is there a way to, in Java, unescape those kinds of HTML entities exactly as a browser would do?
Obs.: I don't know which method or library was used to escape to that HTML Entity.

You must be viewing the output in some terminal/device that does not support UTF-16 or UTF-8, or you're just using the wrong encoding. For example, commons lang3 html4 unescape works perfectly for me in eclipse.

Try this:


@forty-two Thanks for the insights! I am checking the enconding on my softwares, but by now the output for your line is: 1d43f

I have wrote org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("𝐿") to a file and opened using a different text editor and it displays  correctly. Thank you!

Just out of curiosity, I looked at how &#119871; could be interpreted as ݐ¿, and I can't get any sense out of it. What program/codepage/encoding were you using when viewing the output?

@forty-two Using Eclipse  2023-03 (4.27.0). All files are encoded in ISO-8859-1. Printing StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("𝐿") prints  (sorry, I hadn't tried that either, I was just using the Eclipse inspection (Ctrl Shift I) and Variables tab. I have serached but couldn't find which enconding they use.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
